# Distance from Center and Rotation Angle of Points on an Archimedean Spiral

Tags: geometry

I have an archimedean spiral with the following parameters:

- Start coordinate = (1.594,0)
- Total angular rotation = 9495 degrees
- Distance (Pitch) of spiral = 0.070

I want to calculate values for points that are equally spaced along the spiral.  There are 5841 points.  I need 2 things:

1. Distance of the point from center
2. Rotation angle at that point

Thanks for your assistance!!

Comment: Is pitch growth of radius per degree or radian?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formulas like

$$ r = r_i ( 1 + k_1 \theta /( 2 \pi)) $$
or

$$ r = r_i ( 1 + k_2 \theta /360), $$

computing k's from your data.